# Get a variable field of all comments of current post

Tags: comments

How to get **a variable comment field** of **all comments** of **current post**?

I want to display all (for current post) comment user website url in to current post.

Thanks for help.

Comment: This is confusing. Please try to clarify what you want. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To get the comments use `get_comments()` and the current post’s ID.
2. To get the URL fields only use `wp_list_pluck()`.
3. To remove the empty fields use `array_filter()` without a callback.

.

```
$comment_urls = array ();
$all_comments = get_comments( array ( 'post_id' => get_the_ID() ) );

if ( $all_comments )
{
    $comment_urls = array_filter( 
        wp_list_pluck( $all_comments, 'comment_author_url' ) 
    );
}
```

`$comment_urls` is now an array of URLS. Don’t forget to use `esc_url()` when you print those into your page.

You could also filter `'comments_clauses'` to query for comments with a non-empty URL field only. That might be faster.

```
add_filter( 'comments_clauses', 'wpse_66056_get_urls_only' );
function wpse_66056_get_urls_only( $sql )
{
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );
    $sql['where'] = $sql['where'] . " AND comment_author_url != ''";
    return $sql;
}
$all_comments = get_comments(
    array (
        'post_id' => get_the_ID(),
    )
);
$comment_urls = wp_list_pluck( $all_comments, 'comment_author_url' );
```